# How to set the iteration field automatically to latest iteration?

Tags: azure-devops

Currently, we manually set the iteration as Current iteration in Azure Devops (VSTS):

[image]

Could you please help how this can be automated? So we do not have set for every iteration.

I have tried all possible ways through web UI.

Comment: You can find a list of Azure DevOps Queries macros at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-operators-variables?view=azure-devops#query-macros-or-variables

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To set a default Iteration path for newly created workitems, go to '**Project Settings** > **Team Configuration**'.
Use **@CurrentIteration** for the default iteration path. This will automatically map to todays valid iteration (by start and end date).

[image]

Comment: When I try to change the default iteration, I get a _really_ scary dialog that says that all other iterations will be deleted.  Does that really delete _all_ iterations, not just the ones for this team?

Comment: This doesn't work if your most recent iteration doesn't have start and end dates. It will select the last iteration with an end date entered. I wish it were possible to define an iteration without an end date, as I never know how long my next iteration will be. :(

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do that manually.
Once you work with iteration dates (Start date, End date) for your sprints, Azure DevOps will automatically determine which sprint is the current one.

All steps to schedule a sprint date are described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/define-sprints?view=azure-devops#quick-start-guide-to-scheduling-sprints).

Comment: Hello Marc, I am looking for a way through which the work item, for example task, will show the current iteration by default in the iteration field of the task work item form. Refer the picture in the link above.

Comment: Ok, I see... You can use the placeholder @CurrentIteration for that. I have posted another answer below. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am already using @currentiteration. But it shows only the root iteration in a work item. Like in the above image, it shows Dummy project in the iteration field by default. I want it to show Iteration 1 or 2 whichever is the current one.

Comment: Same here. I have @CurrentIteration set but it gives root

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are a child of Backlog Items or Bugs and by default inherit the iteration of the Backlog Item or Bug that they are created under.

So you don't have to always set them manually, do the following:

If it is a new backlog item,
Go to the Backlog for your current sprint, create a backlog item or bug and the iteration path will automatically be set to the current sprint because you created it in the context of the sprint.  Now when you add tasks they too will have the same iteration.

If backlog item exists but no tasks yet,
If you already have a backlog item that is sitting on the backlog (not in a sprint backlog yet) move the backlog item to your sprint first, then create tasks underneath

If your backlog items and tasks are already created,
You can set the iteration path for all of them at once by using multi select and edit (shift+click) to select then select ... menu and select edit.  You can then select Iteration Path for the field and select the sprint you want to set and then click Save.